# Numpy Linalg on transition matrix

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, markov

I have the following states

```
states = [(0,2,3,0), (2,2,3,0), (2,2,2,0), (2,2,1,0)]
```

In addition, I have the following transition matrix

```
import pandas as pd

transition_matrix = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                                  [0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0],
                                  [0.5, 0.3, 0, 0.2],
                                  [0.5, 0.5, 0, 0]], columns=states, index=states)
```

So, if you are in state `(2,2,1,0)` there is a 50% that you go to state `(0,2,3,0)` and a 50% probability that you go `(2,2,3,0)`.

If you are in state `(0,2,3,0)`, the absorbing state, you win.

We can write the following equations

> ```
> p_win_(0,2,3,0) = 1
> p_win_(2,2,3,0) = 0.50 * p_win_(0,2,3,0) + 0.3 * p_win(2,2,3,0) + 0.2 * p_win(2,2,2,0)
> p_win_(2,2,2,0) = 0.50 * p_win_(0,2,3,0) + 0.3 * p_win(2,2,3,0) + 0.2 * p_win(2,2,1,0)
> p_win_(2,2,1,0) = 0.50 * p_win_(0,2,3,0) + 0.5 * p_win(2,2,3,0)
> ```

I would like to solve the above formulas. I looked at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) of the `np.linalg.solve`-function. The example doesn't use defined variables and, in addition, I have terms on both side of the equal sign.

Please show me how I can solve the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your first equation is wrong (it should be `p_win_(0,2,3,0) = 1* p_win_(0,2,3,0))`
You are essentially trying to get the largest eigenvector (corresponding to eig=1) for the Transition matrix. p_win_ is determined by:

v = Pv (or P-I)v, sum(v) = 1, where I is identity matrix np.eye(4)

which we can write in extended form as:

```
I = np.eye(4)
P = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0],
              [0.5, 0.3, 0, 0.2],
              [0.5, 0.5, 0, 0]]) # if you already have it in DataFrame,
                                 # you can alternatively do:
# P = transition_matrix.to_numpy()
extend_m = np.concatenate((P-I, np.ones((1,4), axis=0)) 
# Equation to solve is extend_m*v = np.array([0,1])
```

So solution is given by

```
v = np.linalg.lstsq(extend_m, np.array([0,1])
```

I use `lstsq` because we have an overdetermined system (5 equations, 4 unknowns). If you want to use `np.linalg.solve` you need to reduce it to 4 equations, which I leave up to you (In this particular case, there is one obviously redundant equation, which you can just remove).